# google compute engine - change external ip after resize

Tags: google-compute-engine

Today change the size of my VM, memory and processor. When doing this I did not mark the previous external IP as static. So the IP change and I want to go back to the previous one.

I have tried from the *gcloud* console but it tells me that the IP I want to assign was not found in the "us-central1" region.

These were the steps I took after what happened in windows:

```
gcloud compute instances delete-access-config [SERVER_INSTANCE] --access-config-name [CONFIG_NAME]
```

then

```
gcloud compute instances add-access-config [SERVER_INSTANCE] --access-config-name [CONFIG_NAME] --address [OLD_IP]
```

It is very important to recover that IP(OLD_IP)

From already thank you very much for the help

Comment: I have tried with all the regions that are listed, but in all it gives me the same problem

Comment: if i run `gcloud compute addresses list` the output is _Listed 0 items._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [Google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/RBNLOBA7gHM), an ephemeral IP is released when you delete the resource that is using it. You can promote or reserve an static IP as explained on this link [Static external IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses#reservedaddress).

Note that you can't recover an ephemeral IP.

Comment: You can also refer to this other link [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/configure-ip-addresses#promote_ephemeral_ip) to find our how to promote an ephemeral IP.

Comment: Thank you very much, this happens when the people does not read the documentation correctly before any changes.